# Sequences as a closed set

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Is it correct to state that a sequence, say for example $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{n}}$ in $U=[0,1]$ (seen as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$) is a closed subset of $U$ (or of $\mathbb{R}$)? As a result, being also bounded, would it be correct to state that such a sequence is also a compact subset?

Comment: Which definition of closed set are you using? Does the set you give meet that definition? Hint: Look at the point $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does closed mean? In topological spaces like $\Bbb R$, a set is closed iff. all convergent sequences within it will converge to a point again inside that set. That said, $1/n\to0$ and $0$ is not in $\{1/n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$. Thus, this set is not closed (or open).

However, if you adjoined $\{1/n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\sqcup\{0\}$, this would be closed, bounded and compact. Can you prove that this set now contains all its (sequential) limit points?